# Read from DataOutputStream in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I was wondering if there is a way to read from a stream the same way that the DataInputStream in java does?

I need this for two applications I am writing. One, written in Java, sends data using a DataOutputStream.

Something like this:

The Java client.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DataOutputStream out = ...;
    out.writeByte((byte) 1);
}
```

The NodeJS server.

```
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on("data", function (data) {
        // Some way to read this?
    }
}).listen(4444, '127.0.0.1');
```

I would like to add two bits of information:

1. No I am not sending just one byte, I am all the different types supported by the DataOutputStream.
2. I cannot change the method I am sending the data, I would like to find out how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

In your socket.on() event, the data in the parenthesis is the output.
This should be your code.

```
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on("data", function (data) {
        var output = data.toString()
        console.log(output)
    }
}).listen(4444, '127.0.0.1');
```

If there are any errors, reply :D

Have a nice day